# AS3 PrintJob blurry text

Tags: actionscript-3, printing, air

Does anyone know why PrintJob produces such a low quality blurry results and how to fix this?

Comment: This depends on what you printing. Vector Sprites are printing well AFAIK, and hi-resolution bitmaps too (150+ dpi). How do you use PrintJob?

Comment: I'm printing contents of the HtmlLoader (a simple web page with text, images and barcode). Here is what I get: 1) the printed page is 1.5 larger 2) Text is blurry 3) Barcode is unscannable. Is there any other way I can print an HTML page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because HtmlLoader renders itself as a bitmap with screen resolution (around 72 dpi). I got decent result printing it following way:

- Scale up html body by setting style zoom:400% on it (via JavaScript function injected into page)
- Scale it down to normal with scale=0.25 (on HtmlLoader object)

(got idea from [here](http://forums.adobe.com/message/2667465))
This raises resolution of HtmlLoader bitmap in factor of 4. Pictures will stay blurry (if they have screen resolution), but text will be OK.

Comment: Thanks, I already found this forum and tried it. It works really good (in comparison to what I had previously), but unfortunately the barcode is still unreadable. So I guess I have to generate a PDF and print it from flash using javascript injection: http://www.cetola.net/2010/03/can-i-print-an-htmlloader-pdf-in-adobe-air/

Comment: Is this barcode raster image of low resolution? If so, it might be still unreadable in pdf. Maybe you need to resize it using nearest neighbours method to avoid blur caused by bilinear filter.

Comment: I use barcode font, so when it loads into the HTMLLoader it is not an image, but a vector text. However when I do 0.25 scale the barcode gets blurry and unscannable. You mentioned nearest neighbor, but how can I tell the HTMLLoader to scale using this method?

Comment: I meant use nearest neighbor on bitmap manually, then replace picture in html page (this can be done with Data URI scheme.) HTMLLoader scale method should stay as is (if it can be changed at all,) or text will be blocky. However, it's strange that barcode font goes blurry. Maybe it's not that vector as it seems.